# Joing multiple courtries in highmaps

Tags: highcharts

i want to join multiple countries more than 2 in a single highmaps javascript version.I have tried a lot bur if they overlap each other.
Is it is possible or not. If yes please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to render multiple countries in Highcharts is by rendering them in separate containers and style them as you want - visual output will be the same.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/gb/gb-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>

<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/phrke17w/1/

If you have any additional questions - feel free to ask!